# How can I import HorizontalPager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

just started my first Jetpack project. I want to use HorizontalPager (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package), but I get a unresolved reference error. I see that this is marked as experimental, but using the opt in directive doesn't help. Any leads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**accompanist-pager** already deprecated and most of it are deprecated ([migrated](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)).

Implement this. That's all you need.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.0")
```

Comment: And then press the "Sync Now" button. (On the top right) :)

Comment: Nice add on. hahah

Comment: I kept wondering for 3 days why I couldn't import HorizontalPager and FlowRow. Turns out that was the reason. LOL :)

Comment: you have sync for download, once you add new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

include this in your module-level gradle file:

```
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.27.1"
```